# Перевод FAQ "Часто задаваемые вопросы"

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Аббревиатура **F.A.Q.** знакома даже пользователям далеким от программирования, но в переводу везде **Часто задаваемые вопросы**.

Сайт же ориентирован на программистов и к ним тянущимся. Всем привычнее видеть **F.A.Q.**, чем **Часто задаваемые вопросы**. В крайнем случае есть [**Ч.А.В.О.**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B)

Что думаете?

Comment: только не «ч.а.в.о.», конечно, а «ча.во.» (или «верблюдицей»: «ЧаВо»). звучит, по-моему, хорошо, да и отсылка к классике («ниичаво») весьма позитивна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

FAQ как «FAQ»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- FAQ как «Часто задаваемые вопросы».
- FAQ как «ЧаВо».